# Showing UIBezierPath on view

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uiview

In one of my methods i have this code:

```
-(void)myMethod {   
   UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath
                       bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(75, 100, 200, 200)];  
}
```

How do i get it to show on the view?

I tried addSubview but it gave me an `incompatible type error` because its expecting a UIView.

I'm sure this must be simple.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can draw it using either `fill` or `stroke` methods for example in custom view's `drawInRect:` implementation:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath
                    bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(75, 100, 200, 200)];  
    [circle fill];
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but nothing happens. How do i get the drawing to happen in my custom view?

Comment: Create UIView subclass and implement drawRect method there, it works for me at least

Comment: This is old, but in case it helps someone else: I forgot to specify that my view in Interface Builder is of type "MyView" (class identity)

Answer (score 27):

Just thought I'd add that you don't have to necessarily draw this in a UIView's "drawRect:" method. You can draw it anywhere you'd like to provided you do it inside of a UIGraphics image context. I do this all of the time when I don't want to create a subclass of UIView. Here's a working example:

```
UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath
                        bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(75, 100, 200, 200)];  

//you have to account for the x and y values of your UIBezierPath rect
//add the x to the width (75 + 200)
//add the y to the height (100 + 200)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(275, 300));

//this gets the graphic context
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//you can stroke and/or fill
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor);
[circle fill];
[circle stroke];

//now get the image from the context
UIImage *bezierImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageView *bezierImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:bezierImage];
```

Now just add the UIImageView as a subview.

Also, you can use this for other drawing too. Again, after a little bit of setup, it works just like the drawRect: method.

```
//this is an arbitrary size for example
CGSize aSize = CGSizeMake(50.f, 50.f);

//this can take any CGSize
//it works like the frame.size would in the drawRect: method
//in the way that it represents the context's size
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(aSize);

//this gets the graphic context
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//you can do drawing just like you would in the drawRect: method
//I am drawing a square just for an example to show you that you can do any sort of drawing in here
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.f, 0.f);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, aSize.width, 0.f);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, aSize.width, aSize.height);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0.f, aSize.height);
CGContextClosePath(context);

//you can stroke and/or fill
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);

//now get the image from the context
UIImage *squareImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageView *squareImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:squareImage];
```

**Edit:** One thing I should add is that for any modern day drawing of this kind, you should be swapping out

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
```

for

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, opaque, scale);
```

This will draw your graphics correctly for retina and non retina displays.

FYI, `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)` is equivalent to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, FALSE, 1.f)` which is fine for none retina displays that may have some transparency.

However, if you don't need transparency, it is more optimized to pass in TRUE for the opaque argument.

The safest and recommended way of drawing is to pass in `[[UIScreen mainScreen]scale]` as the scale argument.

So for the example(s) above, you would use this instead:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(aSize, FALSE, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
```

For more info, check out [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions).

Comment: Simple, concise and helpful explanation; +1.

Answer (score 10):

You can also add UIBezierPath to UIView without subclassing by using a CAShapeLayer.

For example,  to add your path as a 3pt white line centered in a UIView:

```
UIBezierPath *mybezierpath = [UIBezierPath
                    bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];  

CAShapeLayer *lines = [CAShapeLayer layer];
lines.path = mybezierpath.CGPath;
lines.bounds = CGPathGetBoundingBox(lines.path);
lines.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
lines.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor; /*if you just want lines*/
lines.lineWidth = 3;
lines.position = CGPointMake(self.myview.frame.size.width/2.0, self.myview.frame.size.height/2.0);
lines.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(.5, .5);

[self.myview.layer addSublayer:lines];
```

Answer (score 3):

Drawing is the exclusive provision of views. Make a custom view, give it your path, and implement the view's `drawRect:` method to fill and/or stroke the path.

Comment: So i made a custom view, then did this in my other view controller `JogShuttle *js = [[JogShuttle alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)]; [self.view addSubView:js];`  but nothing is drawn on the view?

Comment: Could you post some more code? What frame do you set to your js view? Check if your bezier path is inside of view's bounds?

Comment: Just interested - what the problem was actually?

Comment: I was using stroke, but not setting lineWidth. Doh!

Comment: joec: You shouldn't need to. The line width is 1.0 by default (same as in AppKit, Quartz, and PostScript).

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 2.0:

```
let path = UIBezierPath()

let p1 = CGPointMake(0,self.view.frame.height/2)
let p3 = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.width,self.view.frame.height/2)

path.moveToPoint(p1)
path.addQuadCurveToPoint(p3, controlPoint: CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width/2, y: 0))

let line = CAShapeLayer()
line.path = path.CGPath;
line.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
line.fillColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
view.layer.addSublayer(line)
```