# UIBezierPath won't draw on screen

Tags: ios, drawing

I'm developing an iOS app and there's some drawing on the screen, which I'm just learning how to do.

I copied the code from [Showing UIBezierPath on view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352256/showing-uibezierpath-on-view). This is all put in the viewDidLoad function of my FirstViewController class.

```
UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath
                    bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(75, 100, 200, 200)];  

//you have to account for the x and y values of your UIBezierPath rect 
//add the x to the width (75 + 200)
//add the y to the height (100 + 200)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(275, 300));

//this gets the graphic context
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//you can stroke and/or fill
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor);
[circle fill];
[circle stroke];

//now get the image from the context
UIImage *bezierImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageView *bezierImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:bezierImage];
[self.view addSubview:circle];
```

Now this works and the circle is drawn in my view perfectly. 
The issue I'm having is instead of declaring

```
UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath
                bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(75, 100, 200, 200)];
```

in a separate class, I have a variable of type UIBezierPath. I included an instance variable of that class in my FirstViewController.h like such:

```
@property MyClass myClass;
```

In that class:

```
@interface MyClass: UIView
@property UIBezierPath *shapeToBeDrawn;
```

So instead of declaring the UIBezierPath right in viewDidLoad, it's just an instance variable of my class. But when I do this:

```
self.myClass.shapeToBeDrawn = [UIBezierPath
                    bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(75, 100, 200, 200)];
```

it doesn't draw on the screen.

What's the difference between declaring it right in viewDidLoad and having the UIBezier variable be a part of another class?

Comment: Are you sure that `self.myClass` is already initialized when you assign `self.myClass.shapeToBeDrawn`? Otherwise nothing will be assigned or drawn.

Comment: That was it. You are amazing.

Just stupid mistakes man...