# UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext vs UIGraphicsBeginImageContext/UIGraphicsEndImageContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, core-graphics

I am new to these parts of iOS API and here are some questions that are causing an infinite loop in my mind

1. Why does ..BeginImageContext have a size but ..GetCurrentContext does not have a size? If ..GetCurrentContext does not have a size, where does it draw? What are the bounds?
2. Why did they have to have two contexts, one for image and one for general graphics? Isn't an image context already a graphic context? What was the reason for the separation (I am trying to know what I don't know)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` returns a reference to the current graphics context. It doesn't create one. This is important to remember because if you view it in that light, you see that it doesn't need a size parameter because the current context is just the size the graphics context was created with.

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(aSize)` is for creating graphics contexts at the UIKit level outside of UIView's `drawRect:` method.

Here is where you would use them.

If you had a subclass of UIView you could override its drawRect: method like so:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    //the graphics context was created for you by UIView
    //you can now perform your custom drawing below

    //this gets you the current graphic context
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //set the fill color to blue
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);

    //fill your custom view with a blue rect
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, rect);
}
```

In this case, you didn't need to create the graphics context. It was created for you automatically and allows you to perform your custom drawing in the drawRect: method.

Now, in another situation, you might want to perform some custom drawing outside of the drawRect: method. Here you would use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(aSize)`

You could do something like this:

```
UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath
                        bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];  

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(200, 200));

//this gets the graphic context
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//you can stroke and/or fill
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor);
[circle fill];
[circle stroke];

//now get the image from the context
UIImage *bezierImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageView *bezierImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:bezierImage];
```

I hope this helps to clear things up for you. Also, you should be using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, opaque, scale). For further explanation of custom drawing with graphics contexts, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10504806/329900)

Comment: Great answer! I am bested :]

Comment: Jack, it is so good I want to put it onto my wall as an art :) It cleared many things beyond my expectations

Comment: @daveMac , Would you please check once this question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/48761969/2058242

Answer (score 11):

You are slightly confused here.

As the name suggests `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` grabs the CURRENT context, thus it doesn't need the size, it grabs an **existing** context and returns it to you.

So when is there an **existing** context? Always? No. When the screen is rendering a frame, a context is created. This context is available in the `drawRect:` function, which is called to draw the view.

Normally, your functions aren't called in `drawRect:`, so they don't actually have a context available. This is when you call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`.

When you do that, you **create** an image context, then you can grab said context with `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` and work with it. And thus, you have to remember to end it with `UIGraphicsEndImageContext`

To clear things up further - if you modify the context in `drawRect:`, your changes will be shown on screen. In your own function, your changes don't show up anywhere. You have to extract the image in the context through the `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` call.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Nihat 'Normally, your functions aren't called in DrawRect' What is he referring to by saying 'your functions'?

Comment: It has been a few years since I did iOS dev. My knowledge is rusty and I don't want to mislead you. Please redirect the question to others like @Jack