# attempting to color in a UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to "color" in a UIImageView of mine. I'd like to draw a POINT everytime I call this function.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.sheetTest.frame.size);

[self.sheetTest.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.sheetTest.frame.size.width, self.sheetTest.frame.size.height)];
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), _lastPoint.x, _lastPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 30.0 );
CGFloat* components = CGColorGetComponents([UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), components[0], components[1], components[2], 1);
CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
self.sheetTest.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

[self.sheetTest setAlpha: .6];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

ERROR MSG

```
2017-11-19 15:16:54.192104-0700 slate[5853:2107089] [Unknown process name] CGContextMoveToPoint: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2017-11-19 15:16:54.192129-0700 slate[5853:2107089] [Unknown process name] CGContextAddLineToPoint: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2017-11-19 15:16:54.192213-0700 slate[5853:2107089] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetLineCap: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2017-11-19 15:16:54.192237-0700 slate[5853:2107089] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2017-11-19 15:16:54.192262-0700 slate[5853:2107089] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2017-11-19 15:16:54.192328-0700 slate[5853:2107089] [Unknown process name] CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2017-11-19 15:16:54.192352-0700 slate[5853:2107089] [Unknown process name] CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

I use similar code for a different ImageView and it works for that. But not my other one. Any ideas?

Comment: If self.sheetTest.image is nil (no image assigned), then you will get that error. you need to assign the image first before using it. if u need empty image, then use empty image.

Comment: try working it somehow with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(aSize)` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785254/uigraphicsgetcurrentcontext-vs-uigraphicsbeginimagecontext-uigraphicsendimagecon