# How to fill Imageview letter / character in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigraphicscontext

I am a beginner in iOS. I am working on the character fill up of `UIImageView`. Like if image show "R" user need to draw/fill "R" Character then next character show. How can I achieve that?

Example :

[image: Image Draw Path] 
[image: Draw Image]

Below snippet of code try from my side (in Objective - C):

```
CGPoint currentPoint = pointB;

if ([UIScreen.mainScreen respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, NO, UIScreen.mainScreen.scale);
}
else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
}

[tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), pointA.x, pointA.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush );
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[tempDrawImage setAlpha:opacity];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tempDrawImage.frame.size);
[tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:opacity];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Let me know how to achieve this functionality.

Comment: What does your code do, and how does that differ from what you want?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.