# Where's my Bezier path?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to draw a Bezier path, an arc of a given angle, in response to a pan gesture. Here's what I have inside the function called by the pan gesture:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
UIBezierPath *path = [self createArcPath];
[[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
[[UIColor redColor] setFill];
CGContextRef *ref =  UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
path.lineWidth = 5;
[path fill];
[path stroke];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

And here is `createArcPath`:

```
- (UIBezierPath *)createArcPath
{
    UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(150, 150)
                           radius:75
                           startAngle:0
                           endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(135)
                           clockwise:YES];
    return aPath;
}
```

I don't get an error, but I just don't get anything on my screen relating to the arc. What am I missing? This is in a method of a `UIView` subclass.

I also tried the following method in `- (id)initWithFrame`:

```
UIColor *color =[UIColor redColor];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, width);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
CGRect myOval = {100, 100, self.radius, self.radius};
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, myOval);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I also don't see anything. What am I missing? Can these methods not be called from a `UIView`?

Comment: [Showing UIBezierPath on view](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3352256) | [Drawing and Printing Guide: Rendering the Contents of a Bezier Path](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH11-SW13)

Answer (score 3):

The UIGraphicsBeginImageContext/UIGraphicsEndImageContext calls create an off-screen context that you can draw into, then extract an image from. Since it's an off-screen context nothing shows on the screen.

What you probably want to do is create a custom subclass of UIView that overrides drawRect. In your code that responds to user gestures, change the data structure(s) that represent your drawing, then call `setNeedsDisplay` to trigger the system to ask your view to redraw itself by calling your drawRect method.

As an alternative you can set up your custom view to install a CAShapeLayer in the view, then change the path on the layer, then call `setNeedsDisplay` on the layer.

Comment: Thanks for your message. However even overriding drawRect I still seem to be doing something wrong. I don't see anything in my drawRect although I explicitly call [self setNeedsDisplay] in my pan gesture target method.

Comment: Add an update at the bottom of your question showing your new code. You should post your drawRect as well as the touch handling code that calls setNeedsDisplay.